# How to read meta boxes of edit order page in woocommerce associated with any order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to create plugin which will list the meta boxes associated in any order of woocommerce. (Image attached).
[image]

I tried the following code in my custom plugin but I always getting the empty list.

```
function get_woocommerce_order_meta_boxes() {

    $meta_boxes = array();
    $post_type = 'shop_order';
    $registered_meta_boxes = $GLOBALS['wp_meta_boxes'][$post_type];

    if ($registered_meta_boxes && is_array($registered_meta_boxes)) {
        foreach ($registered_meta_boxes as $context => $priority_boxes) {
            if (is_array($priority_boxes)) {
                foreach ($priority_boxes as $priority => $boxes) {
                    if (is_array($boxes)) {
                        foreach ($boxes as $box_id => $box_data) {
                            // Store the meta box ID in the array.
                            $meta_boxes[] = $box_id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $meta_boxes;
}

$woocommerce_order_meta_boxes = get_woocommerce_order_meta_boxes();

// Output the list of meta boxes.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($woocommerce_order_meta_boxes);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Update 1 -**

I also tried the answer available in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56104/get-list-of-registered-meta-boxes-and-removing-them/56109#56109

I Added the code inside the my custom plugin file and I used the current_screen hook. My code is -

```
function custom_woocommerce_edit_order_tasks() {
$current_screen = get_current_screen();

if ($current_screen && $current_screen->id === 'shop_order') {
    error_log('Inside order edit page');
   
        $dashboard_boxes = get_meta_boxes('shop_order');
        error_log(print_r($dashboard_boxes, true));
    
}
}
function get_meta_boxes($screen = null, $context = 'advanced') {
global $wp_meta_boxes;

if (empty($screen)) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    error_log(print_r($screen,true));
} elseif (is_string($screen)) {
    $screen = convert_to_screen($screen);
    error_log(print_r($screen,true));
}

if (isset($wp_meta_boxes[$screen->id][$context])) {
    return $wp_meta_boxes[$screen->id][$context];
} else {
    return array();
}
}

add_action('current_screen', 'custom_woocommerce_edit_order_tasks',10,1);
```

It is not giving me the list of meta boxes.

Output of log file -

```
[30-Oct-2023 07:17:23 UTC] WP_Screen Object
(
[action] => 
[base] => post
[columns:WP_Screen:private] => 0
[id] => shop_order
[in_admin:protected] => site
[is_network] => 
[is_user] => 
[parent_base] => 
[parent_file] => 
[post_type] => shop_order
[taxonomy] => 
[_help_tabs:WP_Screen:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_help_sidebar:WP_Screen:private] => 
[_screen_reader_content:WP_Screen:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_options:WP_Screen:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_show_screen_options:WP_Screen:private] => 
[_screen_settings:WP_Screen:private] => 
[is_block_editor] => 
)

[30-Oct-2023 07:17:23 UTC] Array
(
)
```

I am expecting the list of all available meta boxes with its hook name / values.

Comment: See: [Get List of Registered Meta Boxes and Removing Them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/56109/79855)

Comment: Hi@LoicTheAztec Thanks for reply, I tried the above link , I put the above code inside my custom plugin file but it is not printing any thing. I also tried with different screen names found in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/. I am trying to access the metaboxes available in edit order page location 'wp-admin/post.php?post=42&action=edit'. Is am doing something wrong with the solution available in above link.please advice.